# Android WebView, how to handle redirects in app instead of opening a browser

Tags: android, android-webview

So right now in my app the URL I'm accessing has a redirect, and when this happens the WebView will open a new browser, instead of staying in my app. Is there a way I can change the settings so the View will redirect to the URL like normal, but stay in my app instead of opening a new browser?

Edit:

I want the redirecting URL, I just don't know how to create it, so the only way to get to that URL is through one that will cause a redirect to the one I want.

For example: When you go here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s/ref=is_box_/k=9780735622777 notice how it will redirect the URL to the actual product. In my app, if I open it in a new browser, it will do that just fine, however if I keep it in my app with a WebView, it will show up as though it's doing a search for k=9780735622777, like this: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s/ref=is_s_?k=k%3D9780735622777&x=0&y=0 . OR, it will open the view in the browser and show what is appropriate. However, I want to keep everything in my app.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Create a WebViewClient, and override the [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
        // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false; // then it is not handled by default action
   }
});
```

Comment: I love answers that are like method() { //just put the code you dont know how to use here }

Comment: Please don't replicate the code above. Return false from the callback instead of calling view.loadUrl instead. Calling loadUrl introduces a subtle bug where if you have any iframe within the page with a custom scheme URL (say <iframe src="tel:123"/>) it will navigate your app's main frame to that URL most likely breaking the app as a side effect.

Comment: @marcin.kosiba depends how it is used, for my use case what you describe is not an issue but I still appreciate the heads up :)

Comment: @Warpzit - sure, if you only load trusted content into the webview and have a 100% guarantee that nobody can exploit that glitch, fine. OTOH why run the risk?

Comment: How can i know the url that called into `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method is next redirect url? And i want to allow it?

Answer (score 31):

According to the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation), a click on any link in WebView launches an application that handles URLs, which by default is a browser. You need to override the default behavior like this

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Even better just call  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); The default implementation of shouldOverrideUrlLoading returns false.

Answer (score 26):

Just adding a default custom `WebViewClient` will do. This makes the WebView handle any loaded urls itself.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 11):

You will have to set your custom WebviewClient overriding **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method for your webview before loading the url.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
            {
                return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(url);
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request)
            {
                Uri uri = request.getUrl();
                return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(uri.toString());
            }

            private boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final String url)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() URL : " + url);

                // Here put your code

                return true; // Returning True means that application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.
            }
        });
```

> Checkout the example code for handling redirect urls and open PDF without download, in webview.
>   https://gist.github.com/ashishdas09/014a408f9f37504eb2608d98abf49500

Comment: Note that the above link for an example code doesn't exist.

Comment: i have uploaded the link.

Comment: Worked for me Thank you @AshishDas +10

Answer (score 4):

Create a class that implements webviewclient and add the following code that allows ovveriding the url string as shown below.
You can see these **[example][1]**

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url); 
         return true;
     }
}
```

On your constructor, create a webview object as shown below.

```
   web = new WebView(this); web.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Then add the following code to perform loading of urls inside your app

```
       WebSettings settings=web.getSettings(); 
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    
    web.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient()); 
   
 web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
      // 
      //
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use the below kotlin code

```
webview.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {   
                view.loadUrl(url)
                return false 
            }
        })
```

For more info click [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldoverrideurlloading_1)

Answer (score 2):

In **Kotlin**, to **navigate within same webView** we needed to override the **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** for webview

> If return type is **true** then navigation will be blocked If return
> type is **false** then navigation will happen

```
    object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request:  WebResourceRequest): Boolean {

                    return true
                }
}.also { webView.webViewClient = it }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    if (url.equals("your url")) {
        
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TransferAllDoneActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Welcome, would you like to explain your code and show us why is this the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle redirects specifically, you should do this:

```kotlin
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
        if (request?.isRedirect == true) {
            // Redirect request, handle it here.
            return false // re
        }
        // Let WebView handle the URL loading normally.
        return false
    }
}
```

Since deprecated version of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` cannot handles redirect natively, `isLoaded` flag is a hack of guessing redirect.