# How to set the WebChromeClient to open the new page in the same view?

Tags: android

I load the url in the WebView but, when the user click some button the new url is loaded in the android browser not in my webview. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView, how to handle redirects in app instead of opening a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066438/android-webview-how-to-handle-redirects-in-app-instead-of-opening-a-browser)

Comment: It is not duplicate, my object is not WebViewClient it is WebChromeClient and this object doesn't have shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

Answer (score 20):

You have to use both **WebViewClient** and **WebChromeClient**.

WebChromeClient allows you to get loading progress, for example, whereas WebViewClient will allow you overriding **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**().

From the WebView page doc:

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

webchromeClient does not seem to have this ability.  Seems silly that WebViewClient can and WebChromeClient can't.

Answer (score -3):

just go through

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

you will come to know how to use webchromeClient.....

tell me if this help for you...