# when my app project load the url the server says invalid request but when I put it manually to a browser it can connect to the server

Tags: android, webview

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String a =extras.getString("txtPub");
    String b =extras.getString("txtPriv");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://volkova.eu01.aws.af.cm/login/"+a+"+"+b+"/facebook");
```

when I put a dummy url like http://volkova.eu01.aws.af.cm/login/"type"+"test"/facebook this it also cant connect to the server. but when I manually type in on a stock browser it can connect to the server.

Comment: can you please post a valid URL which works from a browser?

Comment: when I manually type this dummy url on stock browser http://volkova.eu01.aws.af.cm/login/type+test/facebook it can connect to the server

Comment: Have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066438/android-webview-how-to-handle-redirects-in-app-instead-of-opening-a-browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this to your manifest? The app may error on load because it is not requesting access to access the internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```