# Android, catch webview redirection url

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My web view loads a url that - after completing loading - gets changed to another url.
how can I catch the new url. `getURL()` always returns the 1st url not the second.
I can see the new URL if i use a browser but I can't get if from the webview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView, how to handle redirects in app instead of opening a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066438/android-webview-how-to-handle-redirects-in-app-instead-of-opening-a-browser)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use a webClient and implement **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** to intercept all the urls 
before the WebView loads them.

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           // Here put your code
              Log.d("My Webview", url);

           // return true; //Indicates WebView to NOT load the url;
              return false; //Allow WebView to load url
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did that and still getting the same result.

Comment: There are other methods that you could override in WebViewClient.  **onLoadResource** and **onPageFinished**. Probably you can catch your url in one of them.

Comment: I did but it seems that the web view always returns the original url.

Comment: well, Thank you. it turned out that i was using a wrong url. any way your answer deserves to be marked as correct.

Comment: while searching for a solution for the same problem I found [an article](http://www.catchingtales.com/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-redirect/416/) which says that **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method does not get invoked for redirections in Android ver < 3 (SDK 11). They advise to use **onPageStarted** as a workaround and it worked for me. However, I didn't check the bug exists indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
getOriginalUrl ()
```

It returns the URL that was originally requested for the current page

`getUrl ()` is not always the same as the URL passed to `WebViewClient.onPageStarted` because although the load for that URL has begun, the current page may not have changed.

`getOriginalUrl ()` gets the original URL for the current page. This is not always the same as the URL passed to `WebViewClient.onPageStarted` because although the load for that URL has begun, the current page may not have changed. Also, there may have been redirects resulting in a different URL to that originally requested.

Comment: Actually, I need the changed url NOT the original one. what always happens is that I'm getting the original one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case WebViewClient wasn't showing if there was changes on the webview, I supposed that is something about the web that is been running.

I could get that information from the WebChromeClient with OnProgressChanged, I don't know if this would help people anyway, but here is the code:

```
webview.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){

    override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)

        if (newProgress == 100) {
            Log.d("testing", webview.getOriginalUrl())
            Log.d("testing", webview.url)
        }
    }
}
```

This way I could know what is been loaded and when is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You must get the `onPageFinished` method with javascript interface

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.onUrlChange(window.location.href);");
    
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
  }
});

public class WebAppInterface {
  Context mContext;
    
  WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
  }
    
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void onUrlChange(String url) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```