# Website Login by using WebView Javascript Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

On Button click:

```
    public void login(View v) {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rlayout.getWindowToken(), 0);


        loginWebView.loadUrl("https://example.de");
        loginWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        loginWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                loginWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                        "document.getElementById('login_act').value = '" + "USNAME" + "';" +
                        "document.getElementById('login_pwd').value = '" + "PWD" + "';" +
                        "document.getElementById('submit').click();" +
                        "};");
            }

            public void onPageFinished2(WebView view, String url) {
                loginWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

        loginWebView.clearCache(true);
        loginWebView.clearHistory();


    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.mainwebView);

    String url = "https://example.de";
    view.loadUrl(url);


}
```

On Button click:
1- 1. WebView Login
2- 2. WebView show Page
3- Ready

At my first try all worked. No Error, no problems. The only thing was, that the WebView loaded with the page, where i was not logged in.

How can i log in and what went wrong ?

Comment: Liese-Meitner Gymnasium soso

Comment: Nunja was sagt denn der Log? Bzw was genau hat nicht funktioniert?

Comment: An sich hat alles funktioniert bis auf das einloggen. Ich habe mittlerweile die Website nochmal ausgelesen und herausgefunden, dass anstatt `document.getElementById('login_act').value` das stehen muss `document.getElementById('idusr').value` und bei `document.getElementById('login_pwd').value` das: `document.getElementById('idpwd').value` jedoch weiß ich a) die ID vom Button nicht sicher und leider gibt er keine Fehlermeldung aus

Comment: Öffne einfach nen browser aufm rechner, öffne die console (rechtsklick: element untersuchen) und teste den code da. Dann erhälst du auch dierekt die JS fehlermeldungen

Comment: @Jonasw das ist die Fehlermeldung in Android Studio: W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 758

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083066/android-webview-cannot-call-determinedvisibility-never-saw-a-connection-for das vieleicht hilfreich

Comment: @Jonasw leide erfolgte der login dennoch nicht.Ich kann mich manuell über den WebView einloggen. Auch ruft er die Seite (/v3/) auf. Jedoch bin ich nicht eingeloggt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       loginWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
             "document.getElementById('login_act').value = '" + "USNAME" + "';" +
             "document.getElementById('login_pwd').value = '" + "PWD" + "';" +
             "document.getElementById('submit').click();" +
             "};");
}
```

With:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  loginWebView.loadUrl("javascript:{" +
    "ins=document.getElementsByTagName('input');" +
    "ins[0].value='usrn';" +
    "ins[1].value='pwd';" +
    "ins[2].value=true;" +
    "document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();" +
    "};" ); 
}
```

Replace for usrn your username and replace for pwd your password. Use `ins[2].value=true` to hit "remember me". (If there no "remember me" checkbox delete it)

The last entry hit the submit Button.

Main Sourcecode by Jonas w - https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w

Answer (score 1):

(Just an advanced comment):

```
"javascript:{
 ins=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
ins[0].value='username';
ins[1].value='password';
ins[2].value=true;
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
}"
```

Das schreibt username ins erste, passwort ins zweite und setzt das Dritte auf true und schickt das erste formular ab...

Comment: Jo sorry, hab das noch geändert, da waren ' und " vertauscht

Comment: Mit dem neuen gehts

Comment: Vielen Dank! Es hat funktioniert.

Comment: Gibt es eine möglichkeit, wenn der Login geklappt hat es mit dem WebView abzufangen und dann weitergeleitet zu werden ?

Comment: speichert der WebView dann auch die Login cookies ? Wenn ja wie lange ?

Comment: @Excel1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831645/android-catch-webview-redirection-url wer googeln kann... Du musst dann natürlich abwarten bis die Hauptseite aufgerufen wurde damit der cookie gesetzt wird

Comment: Nochmals vielen Dank! Du hast mir sehr geholfen. WebView lädt schnell und unkompliziert.

Comment: Letzte Frage! Kann der WebView auch ausgeben, ob der login geklappt hat oder nicht ?

Comment: Siehe link oben: wenn du login>check>login weitergeleitet wirst, wars wohl falsch...