# Android: Use specific words in webview to open another activity

Tags: android, webview

My app is about a book and im using webview to show text in the text there are specific words that i want to link them to other activity for example: "see ***page 125***" i want the user to be able to click on page 125 & read this page in another activity.

Note: i must do it at runtime

Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066438/android-webview-how-to-handle-redirects-in-app-instead-of-opening-a-browser

Comment: thanks rihan for your reply but this not what i need, i want to open activities how can i do this in the URL

Comment: You can open activities inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
      if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("page 125"))
       {
          //open your activity here
           return false;
       }

   }
});
```

Comment: Now i created my link but when i click it first opens a webview of the url then opens the activity that takes less than a sec. is there a way to hide this.

Comment: That's strange. Make sure you're returning `false` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code from the oncreate function

```
     introWv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

            //open your activity here
            bookID = Integer.parseInt((String) url.subSequence(0, 2));
            chapterNum = Integer.parseInt((String) url.subSequence(2, url.length()));
            Intent NT = new Intent(Intro.this, NTBible.class);
            SavePrefrences();
            startActivity(NT);
            Intro.this.finish();
            return false;

        }
    });
```

I load the data to the webview through introWv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, introContent , "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Comment: i fixed it by loading the same content of the page before starting the new activity.