# Add parameter to url in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

In my app a webpage is loaded in a webview. With `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` I can open links on that page in the same webview. But is there a way to append on all links a parameter like `&mode=app` every time when this specific url is loaded?
All urls with e.g. `example.com` should look like `example.com?mode=app` and all other urls should stay how they are.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think this should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066438/android-webview-how-to-handle-redirects-in-app-instead-of-opening-a-browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your method you can try it.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.equals("example.com") || url.equals("http://example.com")) {
        url = url + "?mode=app";
    }
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```