# How can I force a url parameter to all urls loaded in webview?

Tags: java, android

How would I go about applying a url parameter, ?theme=androidphone,  to all urls loaded by this webview. I have included a snippet of the webview code in my android application to consider

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.welcometomywebsite.com/?theme=androidphone");
        //webView.loadUrl("https://filebin.net/");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code the parameter in the url at all. I just want the webview to apply it to all urls loaded

Comment: inside load url are you trying to pass url dynamically?

Comment: use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` and append your parameter inside. Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32525562/6630837)

Answer (score 0):

To add parameter to all urls

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {

        //appending parameter to whatever url loading in web view
        String newUrl = url + "?theme=androidphone"; 

        //passing modified url to web view
        webView.loadUrl(newUrl);
        return false;
    }
```

**Note:**

When the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method returns false, the URLs passed as parameter to the method is loaded inside the WebView instead of the Android standard browser.

**UPDATE:**

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url){

        //appending parameter to whatever url loading in web view
        String newUrl = url + "?theme=androidphone"; 

        //passing modified url to web view
        webView.loadUrl(newUrl);
        return false;
        }
    });

    /*webView settings can be defined here*/

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.welcometomywebsite.com/");
```

Comment: How should I add this method to the existing code above?

Comment: Updated answer, please check.