# In my android webview, URL shown but I want to remove this and it always open in browser I don't want that

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

When I create android webview then after URL shown in the AVD. When click on any button then then it open in browser but I don't want that type of problem.

I want simple type of app ex- "ashley madison". Please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066497/115145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 webview.loadUrl(URL);
...
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

        }
    }
```