# Why my webView doesn't show anything and automatically redirect me to in-built browser?

Tags: android, webview, dialog

I would like to show my web content in dialog. It can be ordinary `Dialog()` or `DialogFragment`. I have created layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then firstly created `Fragment` which extends `DialogFragment()`:

```
class ShowJob : DialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    var listPosition: Int? = 0
    var offset: Int? = 0
    lateinit var link: String
    val TAG = ShowJob::class.java.simpleName!!


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val bundle = arguments
        offset = bundle!!.getInt("jobOffset")
        link = bundle.getString("link")
        listPosition = bundle.getInt("listPosition", 0)
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_job_scr,container,false)

        val webView = view.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)


        webView.loadUrl(link)
        webView.webViewClient = HelloWebViewClient()
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false)



        return view
    }

    private inner class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            startActivity(intent)
            return true
        }

    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    }
}
```

it doesn't show anything and redirect me to in-built browser like Chrome. Then I read that sometimes changing type of root layout type can help and changed my `RelativeLayout` to `FrameLayout` - it didn't help. Then I thought that maybe problem is connected with all layout and placed `textView` with some text and it was shown in my fragment. Second variant - I showed `Dialog()` from my parent fragment from which I tried to show `DialogFragment`:

```
val webDialog = Dialog(context)
webDialog.setContentView(R.layout.show_job_scr)
webDialog.setCancelable(true)

val webView = webDialog.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
!webView.isScrollbarFadingEnabled
!webView.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled
webView.clearCache(true)
webView.loadUrl(url)

webDialog.show()
```

and it also redirected me to in-built browser. Where is my problem and how I can solve it? I saw [this](http://www.41post.com/4673/programming/android-creating-a-webview-dialog) example and here developer managed to show content in dialog. I saw a lot of examples and everywhere people managed to show web content in dialogs but I have some problems with redirecting.

Comment: can you please add this line in shouldOverideUrlLoading 

 view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())

Comment: @AnasMehar, where I have to add this line? I posted my solution, you can check it also if you want :)

Comment: WebViewClient callback method shouldOverrideUrlLoading have to args first view: WebView and second is request: WebResourceRequest? so you can add this line  view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString()) in callback method override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean

Comment: because you implemented it to redirect everything to the default browser. Your code does exactly that - redirect to default browser.

Comment: but right now I managed to show webView in my dialogFragment, maybe the problem was with inner class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with a solution which was published at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066497/9363441) question:

```
 webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(url)
                return false
            }
        }
```

I removed inner class and added these lines in `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // this is the reason  webView.webViewClient = HelloWebViewClient()


  private inner class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean 
    {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    }

  }
```

Comment: so I have to remove this class and I will show my webView in dialogFragment?