# WebView with no address bar has different behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have a Hybrid App with a Web View. Unfortunately, the Web View doesn't reproduce the same features of the default one. I have the following code:

```
 webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

If I do that, not all JavaScript and HTML 5 code is executed in the right way even with the following line:

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

The most annoying problem is that I cannot access the camera pictures folder. I have also overloaded **onPermissionRequest** of **WebChromeClient**. If I let the web view unchanged by commenting the following line:

```
     webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient() <<--- When this is commented the app works fine
```

Everything works fine, but the web view displays the address bar and I don't want it. I really do not understand why Google has produced such an ill-designed control compared to its competitors. Can anyone help me in finding a way of reproducing exactly the same capabilities of Chrome without displaying the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `webChromeClient` instead of `webViewClient`, like this

```
webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
```

Comment: @Sergiob if the redirects are the problem, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42432740/1117696

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Below Code : 

   web_view.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
                web_view.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                web_view.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
                web_view.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
                web_view.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                web_view.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
                web_view.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                web_view.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                web_view.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
                web_view.settings.databaseEnabled = true
                web_view.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                web_view.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
                web_view.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                web_view.settings.useWideViewPort = true
                web_view.settings.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL
```

Comment: I still cannot access the pictures folder. I click on the button that should let me pick a picture but nothing happens. That is the most annoying of the problems I'm having

Answer (score 0):

```
    for kotlin:
     val intent = Intent()
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0)

for java:
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),100);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)  {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It opens the file choose activity, not the photo gallery view